# React modal reusing

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm currently making a React application and I'm facing an issue.

I have a list with users, a button which displays a modal to add a user, and when you click a user from the list it shows you the same modal used to register users, but with the user information so you can modify it.

Everything is working good so far, when I open the modal I set the state binded to the modal to be the info from that user, the modal displays, I edit the user info, close it and the list refreshes instantanialy.

My issue is, in case that the user want to discard those changes, I can't get that the state changes don't persist.

I have a few workarounds in my head, for example can I save the state when the modal opens and if the user hit Discard I restore the saved state to the running state?

**Im using bootstrap-react**

```
    var URL_ALL_USERS = "/api/users";

import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Modal';
import OverlayTrigger from 'react-bootstrap/lib/OverlayTrigger';
import FormGroup from 'react-bootstrap/lib/FormGroup';
import FormControl from 'react-bootstrap/lib/FormControl';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Col';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Form';
import ControlLabel from 'react-bootstrap/lib/ControlLabel';

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');


var ISRBox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {searchData: [], profileData: {}, modalStatus: false};
    },

    updateList (newData) {
        this.setState({searchData: newData});
  },

  openUserManager(userdata) {
    this.setState({modalStatus: true, profileData: userdata});
  },

  closeUserManager() {
    this.setState({modalStatus: false});
  },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="isrBox">
            <h1>ISR Manager </h1>
      <button onClick={this.openUserManager}>Add User</button>

      <UserHandle userdata={this.state.profileData} status={this.state.modalStatus} closeManager={this.closeUserManager}/>
      <SearchForm clickHandler={this.updateList} url={URL_ALL_USERS}/>
            <UserList data={this.state.searchData} onUserEdit={this.openUserManager}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var UserList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var userNodes = this.props.data.map(function(user) {
            return (
        <tr className="rowStyle" onClick={() => this.props.onUserEdit(user)} key={user.id}>
          <td>{user.email}</td>
          <td>{user.name}</td>
          <td>{user.info}</td>
          <td>{user.lastlogin}</td>
        </tr>
            );
        }, this);

        return (
            <div className="userList">
                <table className="tableStyle">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>User Name</th>
                            <th>Study, Site ID, Role</th>
                            <th>Last Login</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>     
                        {userNodes}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var SearchForm = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            study: '',
            site: '',
            name: '',
            email: '',
        };
    },

    handleChange: function(name, event) {
        var change = {};
        change[name] = event.target.value;
        this.setState(change);
    },

    search: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.props.url + 
                    "?study=" + this.state.study +
                    "&site=" + this.state.site +
                    "&name=" + this.state.name +
                    "&email=" + this.state.email,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                this.props.clickHandler(data);
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="searchForm" >
                <div className="input">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Study Code (full or partial) "
                        value={this.state.study}
                        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'study')}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="input">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                placeholder="Site ID (full or partial) "
                        value={this.state.site}
                        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'site')}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="input">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Name (full or partial) "
                        value={this.state.name}
                        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'name')}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="input">
                    <input  
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Email (full or partial) "
                        value={this.state.email}
                        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'email')}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="input">
                    <button onClick={this.search}>Do Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var UserHandle = React.createClass({

  getInitialState() {
    return {data: this.props.userdata};
  },

  refresh() {
    this.setState({
      data: this.props.userdata});
  },

  handleChange: function(name, event) {
    var change = this.state.data;
    change[name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ showModal: true , data: change});
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal show={this.props.status} onHide={this.props.closeManager} onEntering={this.refresh}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>User Management</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <Form horizontal>

              <FormGroup controlId="formEmail">
                <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>
                  Email
                </Col>
                <Col sm={10}>
                  <FormControl  type="email" 
                                placeholder="Email" 
                                value={this.state.data.email}
                                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'email')}/>
                </Col>
              </FormGroup>

              <FormGroup controlId="formUser">
                <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>
                  User
                </Col>
                <Col sm={10}>
                  <FormControl  type="text" 
                                placeholder="User name" 
                                value={this.state.data.name}
                                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'name')}/>
                </Col>
              </FormGroup>

              <FormGroup controlId="formComment">
                <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>
                  Comment
                </Col>
                <Col sm={10}>
                  <FormControl  type="text" 
                                placeholder="User name" 
                                value={this.state.data.comment}
                                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'comment')}/>
                </Col>
              </FormGroup>

            </Form>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={() => this.props.closeManager}>Close</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
});


ReactDOM.render(
    <ISRBox />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

The problem is with UserHandle

Comment: You'll have to post some code. There's really no way to know what to fix, otherwise.

Comment: tomorrow i'll post some code

Comment: tomorrow i'll post some code

Comment: @Benjamin there i edited and put some code

Comment: Islam Ibakaev's solution below is what you need. You're updating the actual data; you want to either save the old data after update and allow it to revert, or set the new data to a new item in state, and overwrite the current data when you know you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not hundred percent sure but maybe you can do this

```
class AppContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            previousName: '',
            name: 'Dan'
        };
    }

    editName(newName) {
        this.setState({
            previousName: this.state.name,
            name: newName
        });
    }

    restoreName() {
        this.setState({
            previousName: '',
            name: this.state.previousName
        });
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <App 
                {...this.state}
                editName={this.editName.bind(this)}
                restoreName={this.restoreName.bind(this)}
            />  
        );
    }
}
```